# Definitions and concepts that are different for various types of spaces - sources for seeing "the bigger picture"?

Tags: general-topology, definition, intuition, visualization, big-picture

I have quite unusual question. Almost everytime I am studying math, I lowkey want to "categorize" the stuff and look at it as a bigger picture.

Do you know about any resource (diagram, article, paper) that visualizes various types of spaces, what properties they have and examples of such spaces?

I mean something like

- Topological spaces - have axioms of topology, examples are X,Y,Z...
- Metric spaces - topological spaces with metric, compactness can be
  defined in a different way, open sets can be defined in a different
  way, examples are X,Y,Z...
- Euclidean spaces - ....

I am asking, because it often happens to me that I am looking at certain definition and it only applies for ceratin kind of spaces and I know I can search for all "specializations" of any definition, but I would love to see all of it together.

Thank you in advance. If my question is too ambiguous, I will try to edit.

Comment: Tangential comment, but this question makes me suspect you might like learning about category theory at some point.

Comment: @littleO Haha Im learning category theory and I love it. However, I dont think category theory helps me see how particular definitions (e.g. the compactness) differ for different spaces, right?

Comment: As far as I know, there are several equivalent definitions of compactness, not different definitions.

Comment: @Filippo Yes, but there are ways to determined compactness, specific for certain spaces. I.e. in Euclidean spaces, compact set = closed and bounded.

Comment: If you wish to push upwards from topological spaces, see my 3-part answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780) ***AND*** the survey paper Wolfgang Joseph Thron, [*What results are valid on closure spaces*](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v06/tp06111.pdf), **Topology Proceedings** 6 (1981), 135-158 ***AND*** the book Frédéric Didier Mynard and Elliott M Pearl (editors), [**Beyond Topology**](https://bookstore.ams.org/conm-486), Contemporary Mathematics 486, American Mathematical Society, 2009, viii + 383 pages.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova Yes, there are different ways to check for compactness depending on the specific setting you are considering. But there is a most general definition of "compactness" which allows you to check any topological space for this property. And as I just learned from the comment above, there are even further generalizations :)

Comment: @Filippo: [*On a generalized notion of compactness. I*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82114293.pdf) by [István Sándor Gál](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Gaal) gives one way (for topological spaces) of classifying various notions of compactness in terms of covering/subcovering properties, and [googling its title](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22On+a+generalized+notion+of+compactness%22&filter=0) takes you to some follow-up work involving it.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for the information! I think it's always important to think about the minimal requirements to formulate a definition or theorem.